# Different font rendering in local server and live site on Google Chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, fonts

I have this weird issue where the same page shows slightly differently on my local development server and when I put it online. Its the exact same page and the exact same browser.

After some "developer consoling", I found one difference.

On my local system, the rendered fonts show `Liberation sans - 23glyphs`
On my live site, the rendered fonts show `Liberation sans - 15glyphs`

I have no idea what this means.

Comment: You haven't zoomed in somewhere and forgot? hit ctrl + 0 in all browsers

Comment: Your code is? Your font including is? Some screenshot to show what happens? We really need info

Comment: Liberation has a whole lot more glyphs than either of those - how are you loading the font? And to echo @MarcosPérezGude, please show your code

Comment: I can't actually show the WHOLE code (I'm assuming you mean the whole html doc). I'm using Laravel 5 and working off a bootstrap 3 theme and I'm not calling the Liberation font as far as I know. Could you be more specific on what I can post? @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: For example, you can share the include statement in your css for your fonts. And how you apply `font-family`, `font-weight`, and this kind of css properties. Also you can attach an small screenshot to show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Haettenschweiler-Regular';
  src: url('../../0/fonts/Haettenschweiler/Haettenschweiler_gdi.eot');
  src: url('../../0/fonts/Haettenschweiler/Haettenschweiler_gdi.eot?#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"), url('../../0/fonts/Haettenschweiler/Haettenschweiler_gdi.woff2') format("woff2"), url('../../0/fonts/Haettenschweiler/Haettenschweiler_gdi.woff') format("woff"), url('../../0/fonts/Haettenschweiler/Haettenschweiler_gdi.ttf') format("truetype"), url('../../0/fonts/Haettenschweiler/Haettenschweiler_gdi.otf') format("opentype"), url('../../0/fonts/Haettenschweiler/Haettenschweiler_gdi.svg') format("svg#Haettenschweiler-Regular");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  unicode-range: U+0020-2666;
}
```

For example: `format("svg#Haettenschweiler-Regular")` is wrong for chrome for  cases. Please try `format("svg")` instead of `format("svg#Haettenschweiler-Regular")`.

Sometime `#` usage can make like this inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

That is a cache problem. Just view the source, and click on your CSS file link to let the browser show you the CSS file, refresh the page then the CSS cache will refresh. Everything works well.

Comment: Not necessarily. I really DO have the same font rendered differently on an actual server VS wamp.